# how do I cook sausages without poking holes through them?

Tags: sausages

I hear that when cooking sausages, you shouldn't poke holes in them as it will allow the flavour to spill out.

But whenever I don't do that with fat sausages, I end up getting the outside charred but the inside uncooked.

Comment: Poking holes in sausages is generally done to allow the steam to escape, to stop them splitting.

Comment: @Orbling nevertheless, for at least some types of raw sausage, it's quite important to not pierce the casing until the sausage is finished cooking. I've had the texture on Italian sausage come out more mealy if the casing was pierced, and the flavor was not as good either. If you're piercing that type of sausage to keep it from exploding, then the exploding is likely a sign that you're cooking them too hot. The target temperature is below the boiling point, so it's not necessary to get the sausages so hot that they would explode if not pierced.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock: I was thinking more of British sausages, which are a fairly different affair and my understanding of the word.

Answer (score 15):

If you are charring the outside then you are cooking the sausages too fast. Sausages are best when cooked relatively slowly: on a low pan, or under a medium grill. 20-25 mins in a 200C/400F oven usually does the trick as well.

Comment: I just had an experience with that last weekend.. The BBQ was too hot and we had charred sausages which felt cold on the inside.. :(

Comment: Yup, you have to be careful with that. BBQ season is food-poisoning season - undercooked food and cross-contamination left, right and center!

Comment: That why I always dread hearing the words "We are having a barbecue ..." @ElendilTheTall.

Answer (score 8):

I find that boiling the sausages first (in beer or water) until they are cooked, then lightly searing the outside with a little oil in the pan is the best way to cook sausages without splitting the casing.

Answer (score 2):

This is the trick to sausage. Your want to cook it slowly, evenly, for a longer time. If you blacken the sausage casing while the inside is still raw your cooking to fast.

In a fry pan, turn the heat down to just above the point where the grease "spits" and cook for 30-45 mins.

In an oven, 350 F for 45-60 mins is a better bet then higher temperatures.

On a grill, the trick is to let the coals get to the "glowy" phase then add a pan of water to the grill. The water will help regulate the temperature Cook the sausages around 350-400 F for 40-50 mins. Remember to use the dampers to control the temp on a large scale. The water is an awesome trick to help control the temp spikes, and to keep the temp stable.

When boiling sausage (yuck) a high boil for over 90 mins is what I have done. But I don't like it so I don't have a lot of experience in doing it.

Comment: Som great soups start out with boiling sausage with cabbage and some other stuff, but I agree that it's less than optimal as a cooking method if you just want sausage :)

Answer (score 1):

> But whenever I don't do that with fat sausages, I end up getting the
> outside charred but the inside uncooked.

This sounds like your grill is too hot. You can cook with a hot grill but then you are basically constantly turning them over and still playing culinary Russian roulette with your sausage.

I have developed a way to cook sausage with a hot grill but you need to have your a-game when you grill it that way. You constantly need to turn the sausage so that it does not burn. It is probably easier just to wait a bit to have the fire calm down.

> I hear that when cooking sausages, you shouldn't poke holes in them as
> it will allow the flavor to spill out.

You should definitely not break the casing when they are still raw. You are going to be chewing car tires if you do that. If you wait until the sausage is cooked to cut it then it should be OK. Some fat will escape but sausage is 30% fat as long as you do it close to the end there should still be enough fat for a juicy sausage.

Answer (score 0):

Buy Skinless or cook in two way grill, ie., George Foreman type of grill.

Answer (score 0):

You can also cook sous vide at (pork at 60C) for about an hour, then finish on grill or in pan. No poking necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I slowly simmer for 8-10 min. per side for fat fresh sausages and 4-5 min. per side for thinner (like hot dogs), then finish them by browning them over medium heat in a little oil till nicely browned. Perfect every time.
I use the simmering liquid with some added seasonings to cook the peppers and onions. Yummy!